# Assigning neighbors to agents in symmetric manner

Tags: netlogo

My turtles own a list named as friends as one of variable. Now for each turtle I would like to randomly assign $x$ friends.  But the problem I am facing is as follows

If $a$ is a friend of $b$ then automatically $b$ will become a friend of $a$. But I am unable to do it. 
Can some one help me out in creating a list friends.

The following is the way in which I have tried.

```
to setup-agent-friends
 ask turtles [
 set friends []
 repeat x [
  set temp random q  ; q is total number of agents 
  set friends lput [who] of turtle q  
           ]
  end
```

How to eliminate duplicate friends in the list ? 
How to maintain symmetry of friends i.e, if x is friend of y the y is friend of x.

Note: each agent will have exactly $x$ neighbors.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like links would serve you better than lists in this case. If you do

```
to setup-agent-friends
  ask turtles [
    let friends-needed x - count my-links
    let turtles-needing-friends other turtles with [ count my-links < x ]
    let available-turtles turtles-needing-friends with [ not member? self [ link-neighbors ] of myself ]
    create-links-with n-of friends-needed available-turtles
  ]
end
```

each turtle will be linked with exactly `x` other turtles. Getting it to be exactly `x` friends is a little tricky due to the symmetry of links: when a turtle tries to make friends, they may already be friends with some turtles, and they shouldn't try to make friends with any turtles that have enough friends already.

`let friends-needed x - count my-links` figures out how many friends they need.

`let turtles-needing-friends other turtles with [ count my-links < x ]` gets all the other turtles that still can have new friends.

`let available-turtles turtles-needing-friends with [ not member? self [ link-neighbors ] of myself ]` gets rid of those turtles that the current turtle is already linked with.

`create-links-with n-of friends-needed available-turtles` grabs `friends-needed` of those turtles and creates links with them.

Using links is well supported in NetLogo. There are [a lot of primitives that help you work with them](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#linkgroup). They automatically give you the symmetry you want. They also help you visualize the friendships. If you don't want to see the friendships, you can do `ask links [ hide-link ]` to hide them.

### Update

As pointed out in the comments, sometimes this code throws runtime errors and a few of the turtles end up with less than the correct number of friends. This is what I get for not testing my code before posting it... That said, this is kind of an interesting problem.

Suppose we have 100 turtles and want each to have exactly 2 friends. While assigning friends for the first 99 turtles, there's a chance that none of them will connect to the 100th. Thus, the 100th turtle will need two friends but all the other turtles will already have all the friends they need. Alternatively, the first 98 turtles may not connect to the last 2 turtles at all. Then, the last 2 will connect to each other, but then each need 1 more friend. Circumstances like these become increasingly likely the higher the desired number of friends.

It turns out that solving this problem is actually pretty tricky. The problem is that the simplest solutions will bias the friend selection process, so that you're more likely to see certain friend assignments (though that may be true with the current strategy regardless; I'm not positive). Anyway, the absolutely simplest strategy that will not bias things is too simply toss the network and start over whenever you run into problems. Here's the code for that:

```
to setup-agent-friends
  while [ any? turtles with [ count my-links != x ] ] [
    clear-links
    ask turtles [
      let friends-needed x - count my-links
      let turtles-needing-friends other turtles with [ count my-links < x ]
      let available-turtles turtles-needing-friends with [ not member? self [ link-neighbors ] of myself ]
      if count available-turtles >= friends-needed [
        create-links-with n-of friends-needed available-turtles
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

You can read more about the generalized version of this problem here: http://mathinsight.org/generating_networks_desired_degree_distribution

Comment: Thanks for help. Some times it is giving run time error. Could you please help me out.

Comment: This is also not giving equal neighbors to all agents.

Comment: Updated my answer. While the error was easy to reproduce in this case, in general you should post the error message itself so people can have an easier time figuring out what's going wrong.